# Start VS2010 silverlight debugging session with custom URL parameters

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

When I debug a Silverlight app, Visual Studio will just open the page with no extra URL parameters.

So, the url will look something like this: http://localhost:65351/MyApp/

However, I want to add some specific functionality when someone navigates to the pages with extra parameters in the URL. For instance: http://localhost:65351/MyApp/A2Sk9zu

That being a shortened link, which my app will interpret.

I get that I can access the URL paremeters via `HtmlPage.Document.QueryString.Keys` but I can't seem to start a debugging session with any parameters to actually check if the flow is handled correctly.

Comment: just to mention: the sample you gave does not contain any url parameters, they would have been appended after a question mark (`http://example.com/app/?param1=value1&param2=value2`), your sample url only contains another path...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On your .web project, hosting the Silverlight app, right click and select "Properties".

Under "Web" there is a "Start action" section.
Under "Start action" it will probably be set to "Specific page" and shows your start hosting page. e.g. Default.aspx

Just change the URL there to add your parameters
e.g. Default.aspx?test=123

*(Of course the alternative is to just change the URL of your browser by hand, once the app has started).*

Comment: Just changing the url worked in visual studio 2010 but for me it does not seem to work in visual studio 2013. Any ideas about how to make in happen in visual studio 2013?

Comment: "(Of course the alternative is to just change the URL of your browser by hand, once the app has started)."
... and then press the [Enter] key after you change the url in the address bar.