# Debugging With a Query String Param in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Very simple issue on the face of it... when I am debugging a Web Form that is being passed a query string parameter I usually attach to the process and refresh the page with the query parameter in the URL.

Is there a better, more obvious way to do this in VS 2010?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you considered adding the query string parameter to the project's start page property? I've done this by just going into my project's properties area and tacking on the query string parameter to the end of the start page that the project is set to open up with.

Comment: Will not accept special characters - throwing an error in VS2010 for the "?"

Comment: Stuck with your idea/approach and did it this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345382/start-vs2010-silverlight-debugging-session-with-custom-url-parameters