# Query-string in ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2015 for debugging?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2015, query-string

How do you add a query-string to a specific page in ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2015 for debugging?

I want to run certain pages with a query-string with test values.

I know this is going to be simple but I can not work out to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the query string parameter to the project's start page property. Select project in Solution Explorer, right-click on Properties. Under the Web tab, you can append the parameter in the Specific Page text box.

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345382/start-vs2010-silverlight-debugging-session-with-custom-url-parameters).

Comment: I was looking for a specific field of query-string in the properties but yes I can enter it in the Specific Page with the ? query-string appended to the url. I knew it would be simple. Thank you.